# scheme r7rs-large interesting but... is it still in progress?

Tags: scheme, report, guile, r7rs

I am trying to take a look at the status of r7rs large but I cannot find any information
in scheme reports page, etc, just a talk from 2013. I searched around with google without success as well.

- Is it still alive?
- Where can I find information?
- What would be the tentative date?
- What is the progress at this point?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a question that is a better fit for the scheme-reports mailing list rather than StackOverflow: http://lists.scheme-reports.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/scheme-reports

Comment: This is more ProgrammersSE question. They used 5 years to ratify R7RS-small so if we see a draft of large by 2016 they are lightning fast workers.

Comment: Maybe you should come to the Scheme Workshop 2014, to be held in Washington, DC! http://homes.soic.indiana.edu/jhemann/scheme-14/

Comment: Vietnam is a bit far :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read about the R7RS process on the [R7RS working group wiki](https://small.r7rs.org/wiki/). R7RS-large is listed under the "Working Group 2" section of the front page.

In particular, look through the [StandardDocket](https://small.r7rs.org/wiki/StandardDocket/) and [ConsentDocket](https://small.r7rs.org/wiki/ConsentDocket/) sections. Standard docket is for stuff that's under discussion (and eventual voting). Consent docket is for generally-uncontroversial stuff that's likely to get into R7RS-large without having to be voted on.

There is no firm timeline that I am aware of (though I'm not part of the working group and do not speak for them). The standard docket is quite long, though, and they will have to process through most/all of it before you have anything that you can call R7RS-large.